# Processing images from API (apisauce)

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, api, blob

I have a question (maybe issue). I am working on project, when I am trying to GET image from endpoint. Endpoint response with correct Image (but binary) and I would transform this blob to base64 and display it in the

Request is propered by this code (quite simple):

`` get: fileId => {
    return http.get(`/files/${fileId}`);
  }, ``

It's our method which wraps the authorization token.

Response is this:

`` {duration: 497, problem: null, ok: true, status: 200, headers: {…}, …}
config
:
{adapter: ƒ, transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", …}
data
:
"����↵�ExifMM*bj(1"r2��i���'�'Adobe Photoshop CC 2017 (Windows)2017:08:22 14:02:20����'�b"*(2    �HH����Adobe_CM��Adobed����         ↵


��UG"����?   ↵ ↵3!1AQa"q�2���B#$R�b34r��C%�S���cs5���&D�TdE£t6�U�e���u��F'���������������Vfv��������7GWgw��������5!1AQaq"2����B#�R��3$b�r��CScs4�%���&5��D�T�dEU6te����u��F���������������Vfv��������'7GWgw�������?����U�=ͪ������tn�?8��9`�b��GI'���sw
��.�����O��r����u���>�Un1�↵�c   ��g�����\L3�|q���;]�+{l#������R���P�^��}v��+{,n��k����v����S�eY����K�uc�ı�m}_�U6?���g�����붃�1������wa�=՗����⟤u�Ա����0�n�0��.��?gI    ��k�Y]�I↵������Vg�V�ʙE�v��~��k\���X�����v#�����`��k��U�2.��γ��x
i{���:ϥ���'Vō���ZO���?�G�ܻO���U�a��.?�>�V�[D@�Ux��o�u����t��9�Kiv�� �9�����t��������U��en v����c��R� ���A�Wz�\5�vл%�}%��c��@8��m���}P��5�?����n=ud�ZC�ִLn�$��{��j?T�8?� 6c��E��N����w��$ےOX�����O�c��~F~3�k[cŌkZ�}��ӷ�
�^���>�[�#D��i�(�Q��� ����    �����kƽ�<{������v�ͳ�ն�o��t�V&7��ߙ�o���ta��e���
kEv��z���O���P�S����2n���?K��U���Pu���`t�|�uN��~�����W�Z��[F=tcQ�k]�s[u���ī�}lw�"����ӛ���A��-]a.t�y�vQ� [YmV㵬��1�kcsn
����n�E�↵�t���ŷ"�{*q�m���=�sVF?��T�O��ö���_��M�8�]H�c�i�u���;j����«�a�Է̧��)(�v���7��\?�T�۪���Uu��4���/���'�.t������T��t�X��Y�׹��%��OeC$��a��1f��/����W��1��� ��H���O�w��C?���1j���%����s������w�.�';�<����ݖ7�s-�ױ������e�Wz��oq94dn��.���_��s�춿�1fC���Rc�@����]�����-����h�2*x,�o�S��:���ʷ#�4b[�m�ꁙ��X�^ڪ�w=�7���Z�C�/M��������W=����:�z�^&K`����%��}���7��j�5l��Z�S�e��z�8��-��V2��K�ɺ?S��mYn�.�'�����T<]^�F�q3�Yϧm�����l�|�]U�ڱ�������%�eф-c+#IG�[߳�l��� :�I�
�8$��Һ�.~;��<�K\���I6���������}Ρ��@������7Խ�@�kAq���:��G͘����̸r��!��ߺ���ϯ ����$~O�)�c< �4Y��"7ս�~��xsq.sk����t������*M�:GM�/�
��j����h�����̌��l�[���g��S�;��VFF=nv��e�����U�8��<&%8sc�KF���\���/v;�x
���=�8�W�5�Y�0_;���Գ�3����b��ޫ�32�od���O>��m�����a�~�O�GRD�͎�fYsQ�@����tn�~M��e�ٷ1�7!�E��ֿ�
���?�ͮǣuWd�c�6$�O"�k������������e�ݱ��ls�.��e��� �d��??�ܭJ �#�Ռ�6��Uk7��m��:�G�_�][�}%�^SM.���K`��[�%�/ó?�kǻ�ԃ}_Y��`@�9~���#�B�@Sh�$�W��������%u��mq��'n�a<��Gi��Q�7
?��y�I ��5�����}�n��������q1���]y�H�>��    ��"x��D�����:�$w�����_T����썰f>�G��)/+I.�������0Photoshop 3.08BIM%8BIM:printOutputPstSboolInteenumInteClrmprintSixteenBitboolprinterNameTEXTCanon iR1022i PCL6printProofSetupObjcNastaven� n�tisku↵proofSetupBltnenumbuiltinProof    proofCMYK8BIM;-printOutputOptionsCptnboolClbrboolRgsMboolCrnCboolCntCboolLblsboolNgtvboolEmlDboolIntrboolBckgObjcRGBCRd  doub@o�Grn doub@o�Bl  doub@o�BrdTUntF#RltBld UntF#RltRsltUntF#Rlt@��↵vectorDataboolPgPsenumPgPsPgPCLeftUntF#RltTop UntF#RltScl UntF#Prc@YcropWhenPrintingboolcropRectBottomlongcropRectLeftlong
cropRectRightlongcropRectToplong8BIM�+��+��8BIM&?�8BIM
Z8BIM8BIM�    8BIM'↵8BIM�H/fflff/ff���2Z5-8BIM�p��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������8BIM8BIM8BIM08BIM-8BIM@@8BIM8BIM?b'foto2'bnullboundsObjcRct1Top longLeftlongBtomlongbRghtlong'slicesVlLsObjcslicesliceIDlonggroupIDlongoriginenumESliceOrigin
autoGeneratedTypeenum↵ESliceTypeImg boundsObjcRct1Top longLeftlongBtomlongbRghtlong'urlTEXTnullTEXTMsgeTEXTaltTagTEXTcellTextIsHTMLboolcellTextTEXT  horzAlignenumESliceHorzAligndefault   vertAlignenumESliceVertAligndefaultbgColorTypeenumESliceBGColorTypeNone topOutsetlong↵leftOutsetlongbottomOutsetlongrightOutsetlong8BIM(?�8BIM8BIM8BIM   �GU�G� �����Adobe_CM��…y�$�'���駋�K5VL����D����$QP���'ߺx�zPm�3pbhqO����������J�Hb���Z��?�W�}}�2�_�[�Z���|VJ-�X3��EIO����)���()�y<q�=\Z�2�����;u W�N��Xt���\�-
r�M�I��U��ə��ƘS�Z�:Ȗ�6iH,d���*��:1↵P���=%c��,o<�����H��C=d2�K2UD`��M��/�V9Z1�ּd�#��r�b �Vg1�"S־6�*j`��CO*��ʢ�b����2�a�N�U}j:ߌ��:��ỷT����Xژ�kr���ɔ�F�eX_�$5����%� 6p���-����u��9������o5���o  �#)A�!�%�y�$�.M����cǵ�t�4�8�*z]�i2X�A&M�=r+)���%Cx=E��pYSW��@���q�:��Џ.��-�5[~�|�e*F$JP U�OKc�������5�:�M�[nQм���.GQ4��Q�=Qr��;�۴Q]QB��io~�U�H�g)^$�j3KP�gN���Yx�5vP�n8��3�&[$=↵�����eda��q�l�n"��ȥ$�(�i/��W�����8(G[惠���l��^Y�b�;��pa�   L�'dʭ��;��}@�h N�UB3\tA�}���jY��T����ˍ����jYi��5OQ����$�=���N�����Zӣ��(��jAQ%E&3Q-=JG��� �X���;�� K��G�ވ�OOZ)W��Av;+K>V�S缕T�RJ�姉%��;PR��)�`H i�~=�)I����[h��NLn\�l�w����6���z�[��U������T↵�馦����\�k�d���\�JڊZ�B��de�Aq~��:I�{+rWe�����<�C-U�z_�+:Y��t�}?�ߺ������5��%�z������c��w��5T4���f��9���ͭ��R}�c]Js�|�����VSA�T�EYT(p��J��14�$2T#N�P�↵������]J��9�
EԴ�um���dE}]Tyh�����')���k��[USR��@�[�~����=-��g�MH���Y[EWA�X�gDj����EI�b�4eॉ����H�V�)��a��̅5s�Z*q[�l�>DA��!5u<q�r�����'SG���׭u�gV�915K������R�Y%�xZ(ҍX�Wb��݇���P���~�5n�\�Ǥ­7�USO��ɚ\S4��"����U�ж�gh@�������J-�Y��Z����>=�MO+���c���V��鿵u��}1⚺�/&�Ud1iV�ϖ��(e��)�r|��↵܁a���Q׺!��9+��
5M%]g�m���b�uUkΦ���Z��#��}{��Ff���}����j�\���+r2���Q��P��Y,��X{�t�6�ܙ��f��RTF��q5��pKLW�C2���9R↵�uE��:v�=k�z_n�pC�lu&v��|˅�M��v�UI ��c������8�Y[Q��zXq!2Ԕ9�0��a[��6^�T��e;�QCCH��9�Zh���G�~"��U�F����t�Ū�0d���5L�m�8�������0�K�T��K�(�K��Ѣ�jI�mf��a$�zx�f�y<���W?�U��el�{�K�<=$��)�#݂�����ZJly�WcsTu��SIU2�0GVjW�ʡ�#����n�lN�Z��mf?#E������0↵,��1U54��MYMP�B�H�%�ߛ{�F�01)�Mu��*'�R��bq�p�M�"�G����H�0c���O↵8$�0.p6M:v�ס��u5�O����)"ǭ�U@kb�����I=<    N�d,A��~���IH{�����VÖ�Z    *�WbѨ1��-QO�T/�6?��{�W��x���v�gf��c��� YIS� ��dq�pT�E�ȑ$��f��`,����`g+���6u����SY��U/خV����*YRc>�鱘C��X�hdH���BY�m���M�K�#%��z�������
k�w&�m³<�kZ↵#y[D��K�c*�\{���E�AwWǓ��k�e�8�.�ݰ}�UD�X�q�J�U�e���Y��    !����ڙ��[�5$�e2;n�FF�MU<(�uk��!�k���O*
���=z_/�:l���4SaqY7���UYue\����á��������h���<��=�K�����8JU-�玶-�M.�#��?I�~���L�|t��{↵�wo�↵↵��S��xֶ����P�KR������ߩ^���viOJ����i�kb2QͶ( �/.)�b��J�Z��I_��T��Xܓ���a����k�d��x�Yy��-fjZ�h���↵����#���h��4�;0*��<�Ÿ�v���=<n�ã#��E�3>W.p�� �Y�#E��3��y�h�&�(YA�Ϩ���oew�J���5ҽ>n=ٳ��Pa2���OC���H�i<�����%:��؅↵����PP:h��"�3����d*(iij�2�媦�UD��C,�$��$�]DG�M�a���;��ylm6V,>媨H`�i�����>R�}� �:�i�B�Y!~X��WT9#�5�)���)��PU��A�@�T�U�Bw3>�mv�����]Į���6�����.f��'U��3�K����@Z1 �ur,>���ӱz� Qd�ҪS�>*��ejz�`+���,Q���Ӹ�S�"M��ߺ0�vh�E�rn�&��s����4��:*�uUe�)k̑ʦ�W��K٬�޺ ���=,�s� ۘ��ca��z���!�i1�b(�j�&q1�T��6���~��:jzZ��yZ̥Fch%��-�E[!EF��dCp��Qm��^�llNVL���;�LsS�5l4y���gT�P�k�����ҥnx��٫ڪ���й�����Y��NJZjz�ʊz��_4Q�n�P�(vev��_�4��iֺ[dbxpU��,���cނ�P5D�y��hy�<� <�oTLڿ�vIt�=h���@n���}�'�S����Yij��h��ԊAL�g��c�H�6��1����dH@���4�Bԙ�x�2�|�ɏ����U���R��4�0�]A��B�n��{��.1��Em��Ymϊ̜�:�)[���郮3ӊsO3�1����I`]�G���&Ԁ��)���m�v�Z�||  ��J��#U66%�e�i(!ɈVHic��= �U�6��[��d��↵�:*Q�����i$����7�zEgfFyىd� �<�����C8��Κ�#�72`3o���%GL��*���H)�u?c↵ֽL0�D�Yc(����I���+���J���#T��ϓSPƳ&j�I*��:=���A$�}�z+�H�:͎��cæ[���U��=+m��CGC�� h%d$1�ӧ�)s����,�S�h\a!�TEUQI����s��%�u��?R�
W�\X��W3�S��m�vƪ�.!�s_G� P���K\>I��QI�↵U@_�� ��}�I$���������qU�
:05T��e+*?�d(����↵�j���H�#h�R:���Yde7�{<{��(�v�`��K[��    ��X↵#��m%M��K���?�}��x���q�7fk5�gG��Y�M*�'�x��U�ѐ�~Ң�1Ƭ�mN-on��׼W���{���(j!���d)i���l�GJ?{� ���=W H�����R����zU�n\E5F��sR�e,�0�P��ri�%���'�↵↵e����"W�����Bv��D�8�S����r�j�<�>�S��jhy��id�d��~�B���s��<�O5�7��z�Կ�����7��?�$���_�!��������������{p��G�c�.c�����T��p���ڙ>#�t�ˣ9ؿ�d��>_�O������7��������O^�e��I<���_�3�-��������_������][�y���q�����h���?��������� ��N�;��Pv����[�ŷ�/��?�#��?���[ݓ���������O����:������1'�↵�i��}����[�Ǥ����(��[���������_gi�=y8�tn>>�Ǖ���_�n��}��k���'�5����������������v���?���?��'�~�t4e?�����g�[j����ǿ���{�;�=:��?�������-��d�_����/��:��\���}yo�����&����O�tKu���eņo��↵��-�o�/�    ����������������-�X�_������L����=���|'�Ob����O�A������������tS7�z0ۛ�<��5��O���ŏ�W�/�g�S��o~鮂������[?����?������G���������t    ���������t_�q����.�����?��[�����.�У���ߺ?�������Z��������C/�z�@����iK�������[�-�5�W����j�������п�?�]�������/����������>?.�x<u���������
�3�i������?�����ˏT���������p��������o����{;��5��ǣ#���o1�c��C�.��f������M�ڵ�w�t^��͋�1���-�����������}�7�Ӱ�]
�ū ����E�_�������?��L����Ϥ^����������\�B����?�o����?�n�-���������?�O���G�_����{�L�����?�������?�O�_��~�>�և�����G�Z���C�?��������ߺ�A�G�|y?����������?��͏�?�kߺ����kK�3O�k�.5��������?���o�硲������e���s�T���������Aǯ~Ε����*���ڿ���o�7�X�����c��~ǯ~΃���?�}��u���G���&_��L���֟v^-�|�B������|��S+�?�����o��WO���7�^ۗ��7^���"
duration
:
497
headers
:
{pragma: "no-cache", content-type: "image/jpeg", cache-control: "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", expires: "0"}
ok
:
true
problem
:
null
status
:
200
__proto__
:
Object ``

I tried to transform it into base64 like this:

`btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(photo.data)))`

This code didn't give me correct base64 to display Image. Could You help me please how to properly convert this response into base64 or how to display image another way?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old and maybe you already solved this one, but I was having a similar problem and just found out.

For me the solution was to specify the responseType in the apisauce.create method.

```
api = apisauce.create({
    baseURL,
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    timeout: 45000
  })
```

For binary data, arraybuffer or blob should be OK. Then you can convert your data to base64